# python: change sys.stdin.fileno()

Tags: python, stdin

I would like to change `sys.stdin.fileno()`

What do I change to and how do I change it?

PS I am not too familiar with how stdin works

The problem is i need to close `sys.stdin` but `sys.stdin.fileno()` is being used by the backend code so if i just close it, the program complains.

So in order to close sys.stdin, i need to supply the code that needs `sys.stdin.fileno()` with something similar?

maybe something like `os.pipe()` and/or then `sys.stdin = os.fdopen` with something else??

```
    self.stdin = os.pipe()
    self.stdout = os.pipe()
    pid = os.fork()
    if not pid:
        try:
            os.close(self.stdin[1])
            os.dup2(self.stdin[0], sys.stdin.fileno())
            os.close(self.stdin[0])

            os.close(self.stdout[0])
            os.dup2(self.stdout[1], sys.stdout.fileno())
            os.close(self.stdout[1])

            self.log.dup2(sys.stderr.fileno())
            self.log.close()

            os.execv(args[0], args)

        except os.error, err:
            sys.exit(1)
    os.close(self.stdin[0])
    os.close(self.stdout[1])

    try:
        with os.fdopen(self.stdin[1], "w") as pkl:
            # Workspace Root
            pickle.dump('apple', pkl)
```

I changed to something similiar but doesnt seems to be working

```
print sys.stdin
print sys.stdin.fileno()
r, w = os.pipe()
sys.stdin = os.fdopen(r, 'r')
print sys.stdin
print sys.stdin.fileno()
```

OUTPUT:

```
<open file '<stdin>', mode 'r' at 0x7f813ae58120>
0
open file '<fdopen>', mode 'r' at 0x7f813add6e40>
3
```

are their functionality different?

Comment: What is the code that needs `sys.stdin`'s file descriptor using it for? Does that code fundamentally require an open `stdin`? If not, what does it require?

Comment: What appears to be the issue exactly?  Are you having an error with os.dup2?  Or are you not able to close self.stdin[0]?

Comment: @Kozyarchuk seems like pickle doesnt work if i change stdin with fdopen